# Can anyone explain the following output of the code?

Tags: c

Hi I'm new to C Programming language, in the data types of variables section char is a 1 byte which can hold only one character whereas int is 4 byte it can hold the range of `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. So I tried to breach the size from the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num = 2147483700;
    printf("%d", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
-2147483596
```

I expected an error message related to size.

Comment: "I excepted an error message related to size." Welcome to the wonderful world of [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I get a message **warning: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'int' changes value from 2147483700 to -2147483596 [-Wconstant-conversion]**

Comment: The C language definition does not define a behavior for signed integer overflow - there's no requirement that an error message be printed either at compile or run time.

Comment: @JohnBode Isn't that only for signed *arithmetic* overflow?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think he understands why he's getting a different number, he just expected the compiler to tell him that he used an initializer too big.

Comment: Unless the standard requires the compiler to print a "diagnostic" (error or warning message), it's up to the compiler to do decide. And for most compilers many warnings needs to be explicitly enabled. GCC and Clang uses e.g. `-Wall` (and I also recommend `-Wextra` and `-Wpedantic`). MSVC uses `/W4`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think he understands why he's getting a different number, he just expected the compiler to tell him that he used an initializer too big. ------ Correct

Comment: @JohnBode: Signed integer overflow during **conversion** is defined in C. The C standard requires that the implementation define either the result or a signal that it raises (C 2018 6.3.1.3 3). That is different from overflow that arises during expression evaluation, for which the C standard does not define the behavior (6.5 5).

Comment: @George There is no undefined behavior in this code, only implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

This is the result of an out of range conversion.  In this case, an attempt is made to store a value out of the range of an `int` in an `int`.  Because `int` is signed, the conversion happens in an implementation defined way.

On a system using two's complement representation of negative numbers, this typically means that the value wraps around which is what you're seeing here.

Compilers aren't required to warn when something like this happens, but they can if they chose to.  For example, gcc will not warn with `-Wall -Wextra` but will warn with `-Wconversion`.

This behavior is documentated in section 6.3.1.8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding integer conversions:

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than
>   _Bool ,if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is 
>   converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than 
>   the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> *3* **Otherwise,  the  new  type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be 
>   represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined or
>   an implementation-defined signal is raised.**

Comment: He knows that he overflowed the size of the type. Read the last line of the question: **I expected an error message related to size.**

Comment: why I'm getting a different number, instead of the compiler to tell  that the initializer too big like that

Comment: @Dinesh see my edit.  The compiler is not required to warn about a conversion, but it can.

Comment: What's not obvious is perhaps that the integer constant `2147483700` has a type too, determined by the compiler. Up to 2^31 - 1 it will have type `int`, then the compiler will try to make the type of the constant a larger type, such as `long` or `long long`. Hence I would expect a warning "implicit conversion from long long to int" or such, but indeed the compiler is not obliged by the C standard to give such a warning.

Answer (score 0):

For historical reasons, C compilers are very lenient by default and accept silly errors without blinking.

It is quite advisable to ask the compiler for extra warnings and make these errors with `-Wall -Werror` or even stricter settings such as `gcc -Wextra` or `clang -Weverything`.

Here is my trace:

```
chqrlie$ clang -Wall -Werror overf.c
overf.c:4:15: error: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'int' changes value from 2147483700 to -2147483596 [-Werror,-Wconstant-conversion]
    int num = 2147483700;
        ~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Or rather, the programmer needs to learn to treat warnings for what they are: quite accurate indicators of bugs. I don't think this is a problem of lenient compilers, but rather one of sloppy and incompetent programmers. Programmers should know to listen to warnings without the need of turning every warning into an error - each build should be "clean" regardless - no warnings. Most beginner classes/books teach this. So if people learn programming from conventional sources rather than tinkering around themselves while reading crappy internet tutorials, this problem wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Lundin: it is a sad fact the compilers are too lenient, the OP's example is not so bad, and a warning should suffice, but `printf(stderr, "error message\n");` should definitely cause an error, not just a warning. Passing `-Werror` seems like common sense, but not enough classes/books teach it.

Comment: Yeah well there exists a whole market for static analysers. If compilers were good at diagnostics, that market wouldn't even exist :)